# Wordpress editable template fields

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created several template files like this:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Template 1
*/

get_header('my-template-1');
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
  the_content();
endwhile;
get_footer('my-template-1');

?>
```

I can assign a template to each page of my site.

**Question:**

How can I make specific portions of these templates to be editable in admin?

For example, I wish to have a field (which is assigned to one template) with some specific text in it, and if I edit and save this field - the updated text should appear in all pages that use this specific template.

Answer (score 0):

Add widget area to your template. Then you can easily add a text widget (for example) to each page, editable by admin or anyone else with editing rights.

The Wordpress support forums have a few answers for this one, such as [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/easily-add-widget-areas-to-theme-template-like-blogger-blogspot) or [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-new-widget-area). I realise posting links is not always greate, but the question of how to add widget areas is another question, so I hope this helps.